# What is the speed of a Photon?

Tags: gravity, visible-light, photons, speed-of-light, relativity

1. How fast does a Photon travel through space?
2. And is gravity able to influence a Photon's path?

Comment: Related.http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/137140/

Comment: the photon is the quantum of the e.m. field and travels with the e.m. field velocity, i.e. the light velocity. About the path, in each geometry of the space the photon will travel along the [geodesic line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_relativity#Light_deflection_and_gravitational_time_delay).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can gravity affect light?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/130552/)

Comment: Also a duplicate of http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/6406/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I'm missing something here, but is the answer not c, the speed of light, 186000mph? A photon is a particle of light, but as it has no mass it can travel at the speed of light.

As for the second part, yes it can be influenced by gravity. As an example, gravitational lensing (the bending of light) around galaxies, making objects behind appear distorted into a ring around the lensing object

Comment: Depends on what medium the photon is traversing, if it isn't vacuum it won't be quite $c$

Comment: that is true, I forgot about that.

Comment: ~ 186,000 miles/second not per hour